# SBT connection reset error for http jar downloading

Tags: scala, http, sbt

When I enter

```
https://downloads.athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.jar
```

to my browser I got jar downloading. The same behavior with plain http request like this:

```
GET https://downloads.athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.jar

###
```

But adding

```
"Athena"                       % "AthenaJDBC42"               % "2.1.1.1001"                from s"https://downloads.athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.jar"
```

to `build.sbt` leads to `Connection reset`:

```
[error]   not found: C:\Users\user\.ivy2\local\Athena\AthenaJDBC42\2.1.1.1001\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (Connection reset) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/Athena/AthenaJDBC42/2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.pom
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect (Connection timed out: connect) while downloading https://nexus.flocktory.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/Athena/AthenaJDBC42/2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.pom
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect (Connection timed out: connect) while downloading https://nexus.flocktory.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/Athena/AthenaJDBC42/2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.pom
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (Connection reset) while downloading https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/Athena/AthenaJDBC42/2.1.1.1001/AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.pom
[error]   AthenaJDBC42-2.1.1.1001.jar not found under https://downloads.athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.1.1.1001/
[error] Total time: 91 s (01:31), completed 24.08.2023 19:21:49
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: The error is not "connection reset", it's "jar not found". The connection resets are for other repos.